# How onLoadFinished() accept data from loadInBackground() when return Object?

Tags: java, android

i have this code :

```
public class WeatherLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {

    /** Tag for log messages */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = WeatherLoader.class.getName();

    private String mUrl;
    private int mDataWeatherType;

    public WeatherLoader(Context context, String url , int dataWeatherType) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
        mDataWeatherType =  dataWeatherType;

    }



    @Override
    public Object loadInBackground() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG , "TEST : loadInBackground() called ...");

        if(mUrl ==  null){
            return null;
        }

        if( mDataWeatherType == 1) {
            CurrentWeather currentWeather = QueryUtils.fetchCurrentWeatherData(mUrl);
            return currentWeather;
        }else if(mDataWeatherType == 2) {
            List<HourForecast> hourlyForecastsList = QueryUtils.fetchHourlyForecastsData(mUrl);
            return hourlyForecastsList;
        }else {
              List<DayForecast> dailyForecastsList= QueryUtils.fetchDailyForecastsData(mUrl);
            return dailyForecastsList;
        }
    }
}
```

in the main activity :

```
  @Override
    public Loader<List<HourForecast>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new WeatherLoader(this,mUrl,HOURLY_FORECASTS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<HourForecast>> loader, List<HourForecast> data) {
        mHourForecastAdapter.clear();

        mHourForecastAdapter.addAll(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<HourForecast>> loader) {
        mHourForecastAdapter.clear();

    }
```

in the `AsyncTaskLoader` i do not specify generic type, and in the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<HourForecast>>` i  specify generic type, 
the code work correctly.

Could someone explain me how the result of `loadInBackground` gets passed on to `onLoadFinished`? I'm asking this as `loadInBackground` returns an Object and `onLoadFinished` accepts a `List<HourForecast>` and not an `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java using generics removes the need for cast by the programmer and object in java can be anything, since its OOP every class extends Object by default.

In you case AsyncTaskLoader has a generic  that extends Loader. If you do not specify the object with generic, the return object is Object.

Which means in the method

```
Loader<List<HourForecast>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new WeatherLoader(this,mUrl,HOURLY_FORECASTS);
```

You already are creating WeatherLoader you cast it to Loader (which is superclass of AsyncTaskLoader) And you cast it to `Loader<List<HourForecast>>` there for you get you list when you call

```
@Override
public Object loadInBackground()
```

However, this is a very bad example of generics you have there. Generics are made to eliminate runtime errors, and your example just makes more places to have a runtime error. And Please don't use AsyncTasks :) They are the evil. Read some basic books on android programming, it teaches you to use handlers. The ultimate solution to your threading would be RxJava, but its more for advanced programmers.

Comment: thank you for answering me and explain some code, now the picture clear for me (: